# Should I create new context in each incoming request?

Tags: http, go, request

For the past few days, I've been reading about Go and one concept that I keep returning to are contexts.

I think I understand the motivation behind creating such a structure. The thing that I don't understand is a particular use case when using a context in the incoming HTTP request.

Let's say we have a following `httpHandlerFunc`. Inside that handler, we call a function that requires a context to be passed. I often saw this solution

```
func myHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  ctx := context.WithValue(context.Background(), "request", r)
  otherFunc(ctx)
}
```

My question is, why don't we just pass a context from the request, like so

```
func myHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  otherFunc(r.Context())
}
```

Doesn't it make more sense to pass the context of the request since we want the context to flow through our program? I thought that creating a background context is something we want to do only in the root parent, like `init()` function.

Comment: Your first code snippet provides a context with the request value stored in it, allowing `otherFunc` to access the request through the context. The second snippet just provides the context of the request, there the `otherFunc` can't access the request. The two examples are therefore different doing two different things. Which one you should use depends on what `otherFunc` needs the context to be.

Comment: You actually do pass the context from the request.

Comment: Relevant: https://dave.cheney.net/2017/01/26/context-is-for-cancelation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might be missing the *main* point of contexts — supposedly due to poor HOWTOs you're dealing with.

The possiblility of carrying around arbitrary values in contexts is actually a misfeature of this type, regretted by its designers because it creates an anti-pattern (a proper way to deal with context-as-some-state is to have a set of values explicitly passed around).

The chief reason contexts exist is because they provide tree-like propagation of a signal (cancellation or "done" in the case of contexts).
So the original idea behind contexts is like follows:

1. The "root" context object is created for an incoming request.
2. Each "task" which is needed to be executed on behalf of the request is associated with its own context, derived from that of the request¹.
3. Those tasks may produce other tasks and so on.

   As you can see, a hierarchy of "units of works" is formed, — linked to the object which is the reason for these units to exist and execute.
4. When the incoming request is cancelled (the client's socket got disconnected, for example), the context object associated with it is cancelled as well, and then all the linked tasks receive it as it's propagated from the root of the resulting context tree down to its leaves — making sure all the tasks being executed *for* the request are (eventually) cancelled.

   Of course, in order for this to work, each "task" — which is usually a goroutine doing something — is required to "listen" from the context passed to it for that "done" signal.

Contexts also support timeout out of the box, so you might create a context which cancels itself after some fixed time interval passes.

So, back to the examples in your question.

The first example ignores the request's context completely and creates a from-scratch context ostensibly with the sole reason to carry stuff in it (bad).

The second example might use the context for its intended purpose (but we do not know as we cannot see that `otherFunc`).

I would advise you to read https://blog.golang.org/context, and the articles on concurrency patters in Go linked there.

---

¹ Actually, a new context need not be created if the task to be controlled by it has no other policy to "add" to the existing, parent, context.
The idea of derivation is here to implment additional ways to cancel work in this particular task *as well as honoring the cancellation of the parent context.*
For instance, a context derived for a particular task could have its own deadline or have a way to cancel only this particular context.
Of course, a complex—nested—context can be derived for a task: for example, a context with a deadline can be derived from the parent context, and then a cancellable context can be derived form the former. The result would be a context which is cancelled either explicitly by the code or when the deadline expires or when the parent context signals its cancellation.

Comment: In the article, you pointed to, the author is creating a new context in the `handleSearch` [function](https://blog.golang.org/context/server/server.go).
This context is created from `context.Background()`.

I must be missing something but why not to derive a new context from the request's context?

Comment: @Xoroxoxoxoxoso You're not missing anything, that's how you should do it "today". The blog article was published in 2014, and context support was only added to `http.Request` in Go 1.7 which was released in 2016. So in 2014 `Request.Context()` did not exist.

Comment: @icza is correct; before `http.Request` gained support for contexts, one could use [`CloseNotifier`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#CloseNotifier). The context was first developed as a separate package, but turned out to be so useful it [got integrated into the standard library in 1.7](https://golang.org/doc/go1.7#context).

Comment: @Xoroxoxoxoxoso, you might find [these examples from a recent Go Graz meetup talk](https://github.com/anexia-it/talk-needctx) useful.

Answer (score 3):

Your two examples do entirely different things.

```
func myHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  ctx := context.WithValue(context.Background(), "request", r)
  otherFunc(ctx)
}
```

This creates a new context, and stores the request as a value. There is rarely, if ever, any reason to do exactly this. A far more idiomatic solution would be just to pass the request to `otherFunc` like so:

```
func myHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  otherFunc(r)
}
```

If you really do need to pass the request as a context value, you should probably do it with the current request's context, like so:

```
func myHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  ctx := context.WithValue(r.Context(), "request", r)
  otherFunc(ctx)
}
```